# How to make central/south american "arroz con pollo"

Tags: chicken, rice

In Belize, Peru, and the Dominican Republic I absolutely loved the perfectly moist and delicious *arroz con pollo*. Always flavorful and simple, it was my fall back anywhere I was anytime I was too tired to try something new.

Can anybody here share with me the way to make this simple delicious style, my wife knows how to make it with a tomato base mexican style the way she grew up with it, but as we've had it without the tomato base she's not sure what to do to get that same moist light delicious flavor.

We searched for recipes, but all of them were the mexican tomato base kind. Please help anyone who has had this same dish I'm referring to.

To be more specific, I'm looking for the various types of ingredients used for flavoring this dish around central/south America, not a specific recipe. I am rather interested to the variety of ways this dish is seasoned when made without a tomato base.

Comment: As written, this question looks like a recipe request, which isn't allowed here. Could you rephrase to ask about the different types of the dish, or to ask about techniques for achieving moistness?

Comment: Incidentally, here's a link to Google advanced search for arroz con  pollo without the word tomato or tomatoes. http://www.google.com/search?q=arroz+con+pollo+recipe+-tomato+-tomatoes&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=643&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=

Comment: I have to concur on this being a recipe request. A quick search of [arroz con pollo](http://allrecipes.com/Search/Recipes.aspx?WithTerm=arroz%20con%20pollo) turns up several recipes, only a few with tomatoes or tomato sauce. I'm not sure how much value we can add on a Q&A site without a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chicken Broth for about 1/2 of the water needed for the rice, and then use a can of beer for the rest.  This will give it a great flavor for the recipe.

Comment: I also found some recipes that call for adding orange juice and cilantro to the rice cooking liquid. (This seems to be a Peruvian combination.)

Comment: @Martha thanks! This is exactly the type of things I was looking for!